# Get available app memory with Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

How can I get available app memory on iOS 9 using Xamarin? I could mostly find Objective-C solutions online. The only C# solution I could find is this:

https://github.com/vikram-v/iOSSystemServices

It binds to Objective-C libraries, although BaseType class cannot be resolved. This could be caused by the fact that I'm using the Unified API, but I don't really know how to solve the problem.

Could someone please help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system's available memory can be accessed with:

`var mem = NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.PhysicalMemory;`

Is that what you need?  Otherwise, it looks like most of the methods in the library you linked could be rewritten in Xamarin.iOS C#.

Comment: Happy to help!  The great thing about Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android is that the entire native SDK is available, but they "C#-style" it and sometimes things are hard to find.

Comment: Are you sure it's really works ? NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.PhysicalMemory display the Physical memory, not the available memory...

Comment: You are correct that this will report the device's total physical memory. I assume that's what was desired (based on "that worked well" above). I agree that "available memory" could also mean how much memory the app can allocate without crashing. That number is harder to get accurately.